# Basic JSON output from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

How can I modify my code MySQL to output this JSON data:

```
{
"Monday": [
    {
        "title": "Title 1 goes here",
        "details": "Lesson Details here...."
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 2 goes here",
        "details": "Lesson Details here..."
    }
],
"Tuesday": [
    {
        "title": "Title 3 goes here",
        "details": "Lesson Details here..."
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 4 goes here",
        "details": "Lesson Details here..."
    }
],
"Wednesday": [
    {
        "title": "Title 5 goes here",
        "details": "Lesson Details here..."
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 6 goes here",
        "details": "Lesson Details here..."
    }
]
```

}

MySQL code as following:
I'm using a View from a Database to output Days with Lessons, a each day has many lessons.

```
            $query = "SELECT * FROM LessonsView";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records['LessonsData'][] = $r; 
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($records);
    }
}
```

I appreciate for you help in my code, since i'm new in MYSQL.
Thanks.

Comment: what is the current output?

Comment: What have you tried so far to make this happen? I don't see where you are trying to write days of week as object property or associative key array anywhere. Also without understanding the table schema or contained data, it is impossible to answer this.  All you are showing us now is `SELECT *`, which tells us nothing (and typically should not be used by the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM LessonsView
```

It all depends on your columns in the database. Propably you have a title and a details column. And I assume you have some sort of column to store the weekday somewhere.

Check out [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT Weekday, title, details FROM LessonsView GROUP BY Weekday, title, details
```